# How to do Fuzzy match in Snowflake / SQL

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to do fuzzy match in Snowflake / SQL

Here is the business logic

The ABC Company INC, The north America, ABC (Those two should shows a match)

The 16K LLC, 16K LLC (Those two should shows a match)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkAFp.png)
I attached some test data. Thank so much guys!

Comment: You need to write your own match logic? This would require a decent amount of time to solve. There are books on householding out there. Also vendors that can do this for you should you have the budget.

Comment: Please copy paste the strings - not a picture - if anyone wants to help answer the question it will save everyone a lot of time.

Comment: If you are using Snowflake, you might want to reach out to companies that do Identity Resolution on names, addresses, and companies, such as D&B for example.  Some of those companies have the ability to key your data through data sharing/data clean room frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

Any matching attempt that treats string pairs like "The ABC Company INC" and "The north America, ABC" or "Preferred ABC Group" and "The Preferred Residences" as a match is probably going to give you many false positive matches, since in some of your examples there is only one word similar between the strings.

That said, Snowflake does provide a couple of functions that might help: `EDITDISTANCE` and `JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY`.

[`EDITDISTANCE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/editdistance.html) generates a number that represents the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between two strings (basically the number of edits it would take to change one string into the other). A lower number indicates fewer edits needed and so potentially a closer match.

[`JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/jarowinkler_similarity.html) uses an algorithm to calculate a "similarity" score between 0 and 100 for two strings. A higher number indicates more similarity, 100 being an exact match.

You could use either or both of these functions to generate scores for each pair of strings and then decide on a threshold that best represents a match for your purposes.

Comment: I would also recommend the use of the JAROWINKLER_SIMILARITY function to generate a score in comparing strings.